# How to perform distributed transactions as a mysql proxy

Tags: mysql, transactions

i am developing a distributed database middleware which intends to act as a proxy of MySQLs. When it comes to transactions across multiple MySQLs, i find it difficult to let multiple MySQLs commit or rollback as a whole. Here comes the case:

Say there are 2 mysql instances which are proxied by my database middleware, on the application side,  when i want to perform a "prepare-commit" action on both mysql instances, Firstly, i send the "prepare" request to the middleware, and the middleware forwards the request to the 2 mysql instances, then i execute some sql through the middleware, finally, when i send the "commit" request to the middleware, the middleware will forwards the request to the 2 mysql instances, here is what confuses me:

if the "commit" request sent to the first mysql instance is successfully executed, while the "commit" request sent to the second instance somehow failed, as i know, if a transaction has been commited, it cannot be rollback, but this has caused the 2 mysql instances to be in an inconsistent state.

i am wondering how to deal with this problem, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One is committed and one failed, coordinator should log the transaction changes, and return success to user. Once failed instance recover, retrieve log from the coordinator and make sure the consistency. Like the binlog inside of mysql as coordinator, your middleware should take the same responsibility.

MySQL external XA is also a example of distributed transaction which coordinator is client.

Spanner choose 2PC+Paxos to reduce the possibility of one node failure.